BLAST+ blastn fmt output 17 (sam) incorrect formatting
I am using BLAST+ to map some nanopore reads onto my own reference. I am using multiple output file formats, mostly 0 (blast-style visual alignment) and 6 (the tsv file) without issue. All the formatting and column positioning is perfectly fine.
Lately, I am experimenting with -outfmt 17 and it appears that position of the reference and queries is flipped. If I convert sam > bam, it converts the file, even indexing is fine but then I cannot map it onto the reference sequence (eg. in IGV or Tablet) as the "chromosome tags do not match the reference sequence". Does anybody encounter similar issue or am I setting my BLAST+ parameters incorrectly?
Command line is very straightforward:
blastn -db .\\db\\path\\ref.fa -query .\\query\\path\\query.fasta -out .\\results\\path\\file_fmt17.txt -outfmt 17

The output comes out as:
@HD VN:1.2  SO:coordinate   GO:reference                                                
@SQ SN:Query_1  LN:699                                                  
@SQ SN:Query_2  LN:598                                                  
@SQ SN:Query_3  LN:198                                                  
@SQ SN:Query_4  LN:286                                                  
@SQ SN:Query_5  LN:162                                                  
@SQ SN:Query_6  LN:405                                                  
@PG ID:0    VN:2.16.0+  CL:blastn -db .\db\path\ref.fa -query .\query\path\query.fasta -out .\results\path\file_fmt17.txt -outfmt 17    PN:blastn                                           
ref 16  Query_1 1   255 1536H65M2I148M2I1M1I1M1I6M3I98M1D7M1I4M1D27M2I27M1I312M1943H    *   0   0   *   *   AS:i:646    EV:f:0  NM:i:15 PI:f:99.43  BS:f:1194.06
ref 16  Query_2 15  255 1665H470M1D112M1941H    *   0   0   *   *   AS:i:579    EV:f:0  NM:i:1  PI:f:100.00 BS:f:1070.33
ref 16  Query_3 1   255 2053H71M1D31M1D30M1I17M1D44M1941H   *   0   0   *   *   AS:i:180    EV:f:3.10158e-95    NM:i:4  PI:f:99.48  BS:f:333.517
ref 0   Query_4 1   255 3182H50M1I18M1D85M852H  *   0   0   *   *   AS:i:145    EV:f:1.30173e-75    NM:i:2  PI:f:99.35  BS:f:268.884
ref 16  Query_4 158 255 860H13M2I7M1D28M1I7M1I3M2I16M2D48M3200H *   0   0   *   *   AS:i:75 EV:f:1.06489e-36    NM:i:9  PI:f:93.44  BS:f:139.619
ref 0   Query_5 2   255 3819H111M1D19M1D23M216H *   0   0   *   *   AS:i:130    EV:f:1.55958e-67    NM:i:2  PI:f:96.08  BS:f:241.185
ref 16  Query_6 1   255 1844H78M1D37M1D10M1I35M1D16M1D160M1D4M1I6M1D8M1I39M1948H    *   0   0   *   *   AS:i:313    EV:f:7.60255e-169   NM:i:9  PI:f:95.17  BS:f:579.122

I am running it on Windows BLAST 2.16.0+

In case somebody misses it like me, one just needs extended positional argument in the format:

-outfmt "17 delim=\t SR"

